# How do I query based on two tiff files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, query

I'm using two raster (tiff) files of the Global Human Settlement dataset. One is representing the population in each cell, and the other one is representing the type of settlement (1=rural,2=low density urban cluster, 3=high density urban cluster).

I'm trying to create a table with the total population for each type of settlement. Is there a way to create this table using QGIS?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried and why didnt it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of task would be raster cross-tabulation (e.g. GRASS `r.report`, SAGA `cross-classification and tabulation`,...) operations.

However, since the cell values in population raster can be anything (zero, and/or even 20 million), number of class (or combination) would be too many to expect a reasonable output.

Alternatively, let me suggest more vector-oriented way.

(1) SAGA **Raster values to points** tool (`QGIS Processing toolbox | SAGA | Vector <-> raster`).

Just select your two raster layers. This tool will extract values and create a point layer.

(2) Open the attribute table of new point layer.

By the Field Calculator, create a new integer field by an expression:

```
sum("population", group_by:= to_int("type_of_settlement"))
```

(Please modify field names of above "population" and "type_of_settlement" as necessary).

New field has the total (sum of) population per the type of settlement.